# BrowserSync proxy to two backend ports

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

Using gulp I have:

```
browserSync.init({
  proxy: "localhost:8080",
  open: false
});
```

this allows me to go to http://localhost:3000 and the request goes to the backend on port 8080.

Now my app is split into two backends, so I have part of my app on port 8080 and the other part on port 1212

how can I tell browsersync to proxy `http://localhost:3000/module1` to port 1212 and anything else http://localhost:3000/* to port 8080 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986453/309896) I was able to make a small change and fixed this issue using:

```
  var url = require('url');
  var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
  var proxyOptions = url.parse('http://localhost:1212/api');
  proxyOptions.route = '/api';
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: {
        target: "localhost:8080",
        middleware: proxy(proxyOptions)
    },
    open: false
  });
```

this means that all requests going to http://localhost:3000 (default browsersync port) are proxied to 8080, but if any path of the request starts with `/api`, then it goes to  http://localhost:1212/api